# Who is the "fiend" in this verse - Rigveda Book 10, Hymn 85

Tags: scripture, culture, rig-veda, dress

Who is the "fiend" in this verse from [Rig-Veda, Book 10](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10085.htm):

> 29. Give thou the woollen robe away: deal treasure to the Brahman priests.
>       This female **fiend** hath got her feet, and as a wife attends her lord.
> 30. Unlovely is his body when it glistens with this wicked fiend,
>       What time the husband wraps about his limbs the garment of his wife.

I've heard this being used as proof that scriptures prohibit cross-dressing.

A reputed online publication cites it [here](http://fashionartdesign.salaamgateway.com/en/fashion-art-design/story/Current_consolidation_activity_and_potential_in_Islamic_modest_fashion-SALAAM10032016064009/) so I would appreciate some scholarly inputs.